# Twig цикл в ассоциированном массиве

Tags: php, циклы, twig

У меня есть массив такого вида:

```
Array (
[data] => Array (
    [0] => tratata
    [1] => blabla
)
[data_key] => Array (
    [0] => the first key
    [1] =>  the second one
)
)
```

И я попыталась отобразить его вот так:

```
{% for key, value in L10_DATA %}
<tr>
    <th>
        {{ value.data_key }}
    </th>
    <td>
        {{ value.data }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Но этот код не работает :c Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: вы слейте это сначала в один массив, а потом уж работайте `$data = array_combine($x['data_key'], $x['data'])`

Comment: либо второй вариант `array_map(null, $x['data'], $x['data_key'])`. Не надо шаблон загружать логикой, которая должна быть сделана в контроллере, подготовьте изначально данные так, чтобы с ними было удобно работать при выводе, а не костыли городить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример

```
{% set data = ['заголовок 1', 'заголовок 2'] %}
{% set data2 = ['значение 1', 'значение 2'] %}

{% for key, value in data %}
<tr>
    <th>
       {{ value }}
    </th>
    <td>
       {{ data2[key] }}
    <td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Цикл **for** работает таким образом, что в key, и value он передает соответствующие значения.

key - ключ массива текущей итерации

value - значение текущей итерации

Если у вас ключи массивов одинаковые, то в моем примере вы можете посмотреть как правильно вывести данные

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать немного иначе, у вас же элементом массива явялется массив, я вижу тэги `<tr>`, `<th>` и `<td>`, а значит это таблица, попробуйте так:

```
{% set data = [
    {'data': ['tratata', 'blabla']},
    {'data_key': ['the first key', 'the second one']}
] %}

<table>
    <tr>
    {% for index in 0..data|length-1 %}
        {% for key, values in data[index] %}
            {% if key == 'data_key' %}
                {% for value in values %}
                    <th>{{ value }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>

{% for index in 0..data|length-1 %}
    {% for key, values in data[index] %}
        {% if key == 'data' %}
        <tr>
            {% for value in values %}
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Тогда на выходе получите вот такую разметку:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>the first key</th>
    <th>the second one</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tratata</td>
    <td>blabla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```